# MySql DB query optimiser and like keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, query-optimization

How does MySql query optimiser handles following queries?

```
Select * from Eomlpyees e where e.department_id = 100 and e.name like '%%';

Select * from Eomlpyees e where e.department_id = 100;
```

First query is a hibernate named query. I am introducing another API which does not need use 'name' filter.

Should I use the first query, by passing empty 'name' filter OR add second named query.

Comment: The 2 queries are not strictly equivalent. `e.name like '%%'` will not match rows that have `e.name` with `NULL`.

Comment: Interesting, what if there are no Employees wiht null value?

Comment: I would use the 2nd verison anyway - even if the `e.name` has `NOT NULL` constraint. Why count on the optimizer? It's smart but this particular trick may not be in the smartness tool-set. As @aF. suggested, you can always check your version's behaviour with `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Well, I can understand. But many a time we end up mostly duplicating bulky queries in source code. This is my main concern, would you like to share your suggestion on that.

Comment: The second query is prolly the correct one.

Comment: Tick mark the best suited answer

Answer (score 2):

In both cases index on department_id will be used. In the first query MySQL will perform additional scan ot the resultset (after filtering by department_id) to filter the records if they match the name pattern or not. Optimizer may see that this match all posts and do not perform this scan (check explain as suggested), but this may be version-specific as well

Answer (score 1):

You can checjk that using `EXPLAIN`.

Check more info [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: In my real query, there is no difference using EXPLAIN :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all both queries are not equivalent. Second query will show the `null` values for name but first query will not show `null` value of name.

Otherwise first query have two field to compare so it will take more time then second query.